# tomcat 6 HTTP authentication

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have a web app that I'm trying to deploy in Tomcat 6.0.9 on Redhat Enterprise 5.2. I was given j2ee-1.4.jar to place in the /lib directory. I found that after restarting tomcat several problems arose. But also note that removing the above jar fixes the problems listed below. I'm told I have to include j2ee-1.4.jar but I don't know what steps I need to complete to make this work.

```
 First, when attempting to login to Tomcat Manager I am no longer presented with a login dialog. It jumps right to the 401 page stating "This request requires HTTP authentication ()"
```

manager log for this event show the following:

```
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspFactory.getJspApplicationContext(Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)Ljavax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext;
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:274)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:860)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:687)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:403)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:301)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:424)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:343)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:144)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:212)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:634)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:445)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Second, I noticed that the JSP example for Basic Comparisons generates this:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:


Stacktrace:
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:85)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:415)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:308)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:286)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:273)
        at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:566)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:308)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:860)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:228)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:433)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:212)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:634)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:445)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Remove that JAR file. It does **not** belong in your webapp's library. It's a Glassfish specific JAR file containing an outdated Servlet API specification which would only collide with Tomcat's own JAR files. This exception is a result of a conflict in the class versions found in the classpath:

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspFactory.getJspApplicationContext(Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)Ljavax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext;
```

[The mentioned method](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspFactory.html#getJspApplicationContext%28javax.servlet.ServletContext%29) is new in Servlet 2.5 / JSP 2.1. Tomcat 6.0 is by itself a Servlet 2.5 container, but the included j2ee-1.4.jar is of a Servlet 2.4 / JSP 2.0 version.

Even though when the Servlet API version of your JAR file was the same, you should never include servletcontainer-specific JAR files in your webapp's library. It would make your webapp unportable.

If you did this to circumvent compilation errors on unresolved `javax.servlet.*` classes, then you should have solved this differently. You should for example just have pointed Tomcat's own `servlet-api.jar` file in the compile time classpath. E.g.

```
javac -cp .;/path/to/Tomcat/lib/servlet-api.jar com/example/MyServlet.java
```

Or if you're using an IDE like Eclipse, you should have set the servletcontainer as *Target Runtime* in the project's properties. This way Eclipse will automatically take all its libraries in the project's buildpath.

#### See also:

- [How do I import the javax.servlet API in my Eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project)

---

Once fixed that and having a clean classpath for 100% sure, then you should concentrate on solving the actual problems the proper way instead of polluting the classpath. If you stucks, just ask a new question here on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

there will be duplicate entry in servlet-api.jar in your build path. remove duplicate entry or it is missing from ur buildpath. after doing this clean ur project and run